# Adding call to action buttons in cluttered Interface

Tags: android, ios, call-to-action

Me and my partner have been arguing on how the User Interface should look like when we add two extra action buttons (Share and Report) while it has little to no space.

Here is my design:

[image: iOS Prototype Design]

Note that clicking on the share button will show the default sharing action sheet used in iOS, and when clicking on the report button, a confirmation alert view will appear, in android, clicking on share will show the share pop up and report the same alert view.

Now here is my partner's design:

[image: Android Design]

My argument is that using a drop down menu will add more clicks before the user can achieve the action he wants, also it will be unclear what is under the popup.

In my Design we have less clicks and more clear buttons, which my partner argues that the report button should not be visible at the first sight.

So, which pattern should we go with? And if possible why?

Answer (score 2):

I'd take cues from Facebook on this. They keep their call to action for share separated from their report options.

In Facebook clicking the icon style your friend has come up with present various reporting options such as hide post, report abuse etc.

Share should be a dedicated action if it's an action you want to encourage and know the user will benefit from.

My suggestion is to keep your share icon (bare in mind that iOS 7 has a [standardised share sheet icon](http://todaysiphone.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1.-Tap-on-the-share-icon.png)) but offer a much less prominent report button either as text or a similar icon to your friends idea.

The two actions are not related and should be detached from one another.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to understand more your suggestion about the report button, do you believe it is not positioned cleverly, or would you prefer to "hide" it?

Comment: I think the position you have the button in is fine however on touch devices you touch target should be around 44px and you'll struggle to get the share and report button side by side without misclicks from users.